# Change project to run VS2012 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, projects-and-solutions

How can I change the project to run in VS2012 for C++?

Here I have two projects in one solution. Both have a main function and only the first one is always running. I would like to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not about programming but You can Right Click on Other project and select **Set as StartUp Project**. Or Right click and **Debug->Start new instance**

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a project, choose - **Set as StartUp project**. More info on the subject: [How to: Set Startup Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx).